# Send HttpResponse(status=200) without "returning" - where to send?

Tags: python, django, httpresponse, slack-api

I am using the Slack Events API to record conversations with my slackbot.

The Events API pushes the messages to my Django server with an HTTP POST.  Slack expects an HTTP 200 response within 3 seconds, or else they will re-POST the message.

I want to store / process the Event, but I'm not sure that the processing will complete in 3 seconds.  I want to send the HTTP Status 200 back to Slack and then continue the process, but **I don't know where to send it**.  Usually, I `return HttpResponse(status=200)` and python manages the destination / sending.

How do I identify the response URI?  Can I send the `HTTP Status 200` w/ `urllib2`?

```
import json
import urllib2
from django.http import HttpResponse

def processEvent(event):
    # do some stuff that takes longer than 3 seconds
    return

def incomingEvent(request):
    event = json.loads(request.body)
    url = request.?????
    req = urllib2.Request(url, HttpResponse(200))
    processEvent(event)
```

Comment: You can't use urllib2 to return a response like this. The usual approach would be to use something like [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) to run the `processEvent` task asynchronously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea of this kind of process is to launch an asynchronous task with the long process, and return quickly the response to sender (Slack server in this case).

But how to execute this processEvent() asynchronously? You have plenty of solutions. You can create a new thread and configure the process to run inside this new thread, but it's not a very common way when working with Django.

Have a look at python libraries specialized in asynchronous jobs execution. A very common library to do that is [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

Finally, your view become something like this:

```
@app.task
def processEvent(event):
    # do some stuff that takes longer than 3 seconds
    return

def incomingEvent(request):
    event = json.loads(request.body)
    processEvent.delay(event)
    return HttpResponse()
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to send anything, the only way to return a response the way you've always done - by returning a `Reponse` object in django. This sort of soft-realtime is a common issue in websites because generally responses need to be returned quickly or the user (in this case service) are not happy with the results.

Generally in such cases you want to save the data to process somewhere and return to the client right away. Basically, you want **asynchronous processing**. You could do it manually by creating a new thread and backgrounding it so the call can return right away, but you're likely to have bugs and this is an already solved problem.

Enter [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html) - it's made for asynchronous jobs like this. Write some functions, attach them to Celery, and call them in the background with Celery allowing you to easily fit within that 3 second time limit.

Of course this requires some set up and external software but it's worth it in the long run. But if you're really constrained and need a poor man's solution, you can quickly save the incoming data to some queue in the database and take your sweet time processing it with a cron job that runs every minute or so.